# Persisting data to database leads to illegal state exception

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a JPA question.

Let's say I have an entity set up as followed (only a hypothetical).

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "TESTTABLE")
public class TestTable {

@Id
@Basic (optional = false)
private String id;

@JoinColumn(name="TESTID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@OneToOne(optional = true)
private TestTable testId;

}
```

Basically, 
--=--=--=---=----
|TestTable.......   |
--=--=--=---=---- 
| String id..........|<-----------------------| 
| String testId....|-----------TestId = id | 
--=--=--=--=--=-= 

I have foreign_key constraints set up in the DB and, codewise, I am expecting the normal "integrity constraint violated - parent key not found" constraint to be returned if the value entered for the testId does not have a corresponding id value in TestTable (so if the only entries I had were (1, null) and (2, 1), (3, 17) would result in failure).

However, when I try to persist an entry such as the forementioned (3, 17) to the database, I get an IllegalStateException error (because I have no CascadeType.PERSIST and I am trying to persist an object that does not exist in the db). I get that this is expected behavior, but is there anyway to bypass this and just let the database handle it (and thus return the expected constraint)?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post how are you trying to persist (3, 17)? Because to do that you need to first fetch the TestTable entity with id 17 and then set that to new entity with id 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just use cascade PERSIST in the relationship.

In EclipseLink you can also use the persistence unit property,

```
"eclipselink.persistence-context.commit-without-persist-rules"="true"
```

Comment: cascade.PERSIST added the nonexistent entity into the table (so now there's a (3,17) and a (17, null)). I do not want that to happen. Unfortunately, I think modifying the eclipseLink setting is out of the question as well.

Comment: So, it is a new object, but you don't want to persist it?  Where did it come from?  You can use getReference() to get a reference to an existing object using the Id, if this object does not actually exist, it will cause your desired constraint error.

Comment: It's an error case essentially. Either someone "jumped the gun" and provided (3, 17) before (17, 1) exists or "typo'd" (3, 17) when they meant (3, 1).